# Prevent Marshal From Escaping Quotes on String Field of Struct

Tags: json, go

I am having an issue parsing the following structure, where JsonData is a string of JSON stored in a database.

```
type User struct {
    Id          uint64  `json:"user_id"`
    JsonData    string  `json:"data"`
}

user := &User {
    Id: 444,
    JsonData: `{"field_a": 73, "field_b": "a string"}`,
}
```

If I json.Marshal this, it will escape the quotes but that will give me the JSON:

```
{
    "user_id" : 444,
    "data": "{\"field_a\": 73, \"field_b\": \"a string\"}"
}
```

Is there a way to tell the marshaller to avoid escaping the JsonData string and putting it in quotes, so it looks like this?

```
{
    "user_id" : 444,
    "data": {"field_a": 73, "field_b": "a string"}
}
```

I would prefer to not jump through too many hoops like creating an entirely new User-like object and/or unmarshaling/remarshaling the string etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems like [RawMessage](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) is what you are looking for:

> RawMessage is a raw encoded JSON object. It implements Marshaler and Unmarshaler and can be used to delay JSON decoding or precompute a JSON encoding.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/MFNQlISy-o.

Comment: That's the ticket! Though since I am also pulling in from SQL with `row.Scan(&user.Data)`, I just added a field to the struct called RawData and used that to export the JSON on the same struct.

Comment: @BlinkyTop how did you implement that RawData ? I'm experiencing the same issue, 4 years later :D I use `json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)` in my API and it escapes all Json data from various structs. I'd like to tell it not to do so. For example, Ruby on Rails server will skip escaping json objects when it knows that it's appending them to the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the 'string' tag on the field, which will tell the marshaller that the field is already in JSON:

```
type User struct {
    Id        uint64 `json:"user_id"`
    JsonData  string `json:"data,string"`
}
```

Comment: The "string" option signals that a field is stored as JSON inside a JSON-encoded string.

see https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

`,string` will add additional character escape, which is not intended usage here.